# Android: 3 TextViews, middle one should be vertically centered

Tags: android, layout

i'm struggling with a layout issue at the moment.
In fact i need 3 TextViews: one at the top,  one in the middle, one at the bottom.

The middle one should fill the screen, the top & bottom one should only get as much space as they need for showing the text.
How to realize this layout?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could also do this with a LinearLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="TextView"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Are you sure that's going to work without specifying a weight for the top and bottom TextViews?

Comment: Yes.  What happens is that it sets those weights to 0 and they get pushed to the edges by the one in the middle.

Comment: Interesting to know, thanks. I've never done it that way - I'd generally use weights such as 1:8:1 to give 10%/80%/10% for something like the OP's requirement. Perhaps I'm just a control freak. :)

Comment: This allows you to take up any left over room so you don't have to keep coming back and tweaking it as you make changes elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/l1"

    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"></TextView>
    <TextView android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="TextView"
        ></TextView>
    <TextView android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView1" android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_above ="@id/textView3" android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:text="TextssssssssssssssssView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" ></TextView>



</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: the middle one fills almost the entire screen with its text in the middle

Comment: works perfectly for me. tried it and then gave you the code. what is happening on your end? Added xml declaration on first line now though.

Comment: Change the background on each your textviews so they are different. Notice how they are overlapping each other.

Comment: sorry, didn't notice the overlap. changed the code in answer. Check and see if it helps you .